# With Entity Framework, how do I query for numerical values around a given number?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

How would I query for values near a certain number.

I.E. suppose the database had a table with one column, and int, and that table was populated with every number from 1 – 1000.

How would I write a query so that if I had 100 it would return:
96, 97, 98, 99, 100, 101, 102, 103, 104

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int myNumber = 100;
int myRange = 4;

List<int> resultList = context.MyEntities
    .Where(x => x.MyInt>=myNumber-myRange && x.MyInt<=myNumber+myRange)
    .Select(x => x.MyInt)
    .ToList();
```

It would give the result in your example but somehow I have the feeling this is not the general solution you are looking for.

Comment: I've been living in JPA land for the past few years and I just need to see how something like this is done.  Thanks.